# cordova android change user agent by intercept request

Tags: android, cordova

I tried create a webviewclient like this:

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new SystemWebViewClient(finalSysWebViewEngine) {

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading (WebView view, String url ){
        if (url != null && url.indexOf("mobile") >= 0) {
            view.getSettings().setUserAgentString("mobile-ua");
        } else {
            view.getSettings().setUserAgentString("desktop-ua");
        }
        return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
    }

    @Override
    public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest (WebView view, String url) {
        if (url != null && url.indexOf("mobile") >= 0) {
            view.getSettings().setUserAgentString("mobile-ua");
        } else {
            view.getSettings().setUserAgentString("desktop-ua");
        }
        return super.shouldInterceptRequest(view, url);
    }
}
```

if change user agent in `shouldInterceptRequest`,application will crash.
`shouldOverrideUrlLoading` never called.
I use ajax do the request.